# Set Initial Value of a object

Tags: c#, epicorerp

I am a code newbie in the process of learning what all this stuff does/means. This code was given to me to set a shape to a certain color and text based on the value of a checkbox. I want to set the default value to the false case as a new record will have the checkbox set to false. Here is the code.

```
private static void chkbxOpnExp_AfterCheckStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
{
    try 
    {
        switch (chkbxOpnExp.Checked) 
        {
            case true:
            {
                shpeOpenExp.Status = (Epicor.Mfg.UI.FrameWork.StatusTypes)2;
                shpeOpenExp.EnabledCaption = "OPEN EXCEPTION!";
                break;
            }
             case false:
             {
                shpeOpenExp.Status = (Epicor.Mfg.UI.FrameWork.StatusTypes)0;
                shpeOpenExp.EnabledCaption = "No Exception";
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Exception thrown by EnableAdderCheck " + "\r\n" + "Source:  " +
            ex.Source + "\r\n" + "Message:  " + ex.Message + "\r\n" 
            + "StackTrace:  " + ex.StackTrace, "Error Message:"); 
    }
}
```

Thank you for any insight into how to solve this.

Comment: booleans are False by default, and checkboxes are usually unchecked by default.

Comment: what have you tried so far? please show us some effort instead of asking us to solve your problem.

Comment: And please put a bit more effort into formatting your code in future - there's no reason to have everything indented massively as per the original code.

Comment: I formatted your code for you @MRCromer also when using a switch case statement when you are executing more than one operation it's best to wrap that code block around a `{ }` also look up how to use the `default:` key word in your switch statement as well I would also suggest reading up on the `string.Format()` function so that you can format your Message in a more readable fashion along with the `string.Join or string.Concat` function.. just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Well this code is a function that was created and wired to the `AfterCheckStateChanged` event of the `chkbxOpnExp` checkbox. You can see that it has `chkbxOpnExp` hardcoded as the object to check the `Checked` property on.

I am guessing that you want this code to run when your form loads or at some particular point in time before the user actually checks or unchecks the checkbox. Assuming the checkbox is unchecked (if it isn't then set the `Checked` property to false), you can call this function in your Form_Load event or something if you want:

```
chkbxOpnExp_AfterCheckStateChanged(chkbcOpnExp, new System.EventArgs());
```

Or since the checkbox and other objects are hardcoded, move the code into a simplified function, call that from wherever you want and also from within the event.